# How do I Plot Dates and Decimals from Lists Inside Lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I haven't used matplotlib in years, but now for a project, I wanted to use it. I have lists of dates and decimal values inside a list. There are ~300 records, so here's a small snippet of that:

```
[['2015-01-08', '174.0'], ['2015-01-09', '172.0'], ['2015-01-11', '170.5']]
```

As you can tell, there are some gaps in the data, which sometimes last weeks. I want to plot all these values in a graph, with the time and decimal values. I don't know what to do. All help is appreciated. If it helps, here is an example of what I want it to look like (Without all the styling, of course):
[image]

Also, here is all the data, if needed: https://pastebin.com/esEPp78j

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With pure matplotlib:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [['2015-01-08', '174.0'], ['2015-01-09', '172.0'], ['2015-01-11', '170.5']]

dates = [datetime.strptime(d[0], "%Y-%m-%d") for d in a]
values = [float(d[1]) for d in a]

plt.plot(dates, values)

plt.show()
```

With numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [['2015-01-08', '174.0'], ['2015-01-09', '172.0'], ['2015-01-11', '170.5']]

dates, values = np.array(a).T
dates = dates.astype(np.datetime64)
values = values.astype(float)

plt.plot(dates, values)

plt.show()
```

With pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [['2015-01-08', '174.0'], ['2015-01-09', '172.0'], ['2015-01-11', '170.5']]

df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=["dates", "values"])
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dates"])
df["values"] = pd.to_numeric(df["values"])

plt.plot("dates", "values", data=df)

plt.show()
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/5SkY582 - Doesn't seem to work. No errors, but values are mixed up.

Comment: Oh well, the above solutions all assume the data to be sorted. Of course you could sort afterwards, but I would tend to think that if the data comes unsorted there might be a problem of data integrity?

Comment: The data is already sorted in date order (I think, but I'll check again). It could because of the gaps in the data, but I doubt it.

Comment: No I mean it's pretty obvious what happens, namely that you have one date of 2019 sourrounded by dates from 2015, something like `[['2015-01-08', '174.0'], ['2019-01-09', '172.0'], ['2015-01-11', '170.5']]`